# Problems with compatible search bar in Android fragment

Tags: android, search, android-fragments

I am driving myself nuts trying to figure out how to make the search bar (in the ActionBar) work properly but still maintain compatibility back to Gingerbread. The first problem I'm having is that just putting the v7 support library jar in the libs folder, or adding it as a dependency, does not work: I get an error in the menu xml "No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionViewClass' in package... I assume this is because the jar has no resources in it. The only way I've found to solve this first problem is to download the actual v7 support project, import into Eclipse, and then have my project point to the v7 library. Is this the only way?

Secondly, I can't for the life of me make onNewIntent in the activity be called. When I click the search icon, the search edit text opens fine. I then enter some text and click the search key (or enter in the sim) and nothing happens. onNewIntent should be called as I've set up the activity as a search intent in the manifest, but nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

My manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.random.search.SearchBarCompatActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme/AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

My activity:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.random.R;

public class SearchBarCompatActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state)
{
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_and_activity_container);

    TextView mDescriptionBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc_box);
    if (mDescriptionBox != null)
          mDescriptionBox.setText(getString(R.string.search_bar_compat_desc));

    // Load main fragment
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment mainFragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (mainFragment == null) {
        mainFragment = new SearchBarCompatFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment).commit();
    }
}

/** On New Intent
 * 
 * Called automatically when a new search string has been sent. Calls the
 * fragment to display the string in a Toast.
 * 
 * @param intent
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("Activity", "New Intent received.");

    setIntent(intent);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) 
    {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        SearchBarCompatFragment frag = (SearchBarCompatFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        frag.showSearchString(query);
    }
}
```

}

My fragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.random.R;

public class SearchBarCompatFragment extends Fragment
{

private Context mContext;
private SearchView mSearchField;


/** On Create */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.mContext = getActivity();

    // Enable menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

/** On Create Options Menu
 * 
 * Inflates the menu
 * 
 * @param Menu menu
 * @param MenuInflater inflater
 */
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_bar_compat_menu, menu);
    Log.d("Fragment", "Creating options menu...");

    mSearchField = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));

    if (mSearchField != null)
    {
        mSearchField.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        SearchManager sm = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchField.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        mSearchField.setQuery(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY), false);
    }

}

/** On Options Item Selected
 * 
 * Handle Quit and Sync menu items.
 * 
 * @param MenuItem item
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    Log.d("Fragment", "onOptionsItemSelected called");
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_search:
            getActivity().onSearchRequested();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/** Show Search String
 * 
 * Called from Activity when a search string is returned. Shows
 * that a Fragment can deal with the results.
 * 
 * @param query
 */
public void showSearchString(String query)
{
    Log.d("Fragment", "Displaying toast...");
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Search string: " + query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

My searchable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search"  >
</Searchable>
```

Comment: Wow, I've stumped a lot of people. I'm glad to know I'm not crazy and it's not something simple.

Comment: Even if someone could just put a link to an example that works, I would appreciate it. It would have to be compatible with Gingerbread and use the compatibility libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know. The F%^k!@g problem was the "Searchable" tag **was upper-cased** in the s`earchable.xml` file. **It needs to be all lowercase.** Thank you Eclipse for telling me!